# Disable Page Visibility API in Chrome extension for Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome-extension

I am writting an extension which collecting some information on a facebook page (don't use GraphAPI because of some reasons). As far as I known, the facebook page load is lazy loading, therefore I needs to scroll down to force the page loading more data.
However the page load only if I active the tab, if I switch to other tabs, the page doesn't load and the extension is stuck.

I have researched on stackoverflow and google and it seems it is using page visibility API to stopping the loading.
I have tried the solution in the following link but it doesn't work for facebook [Chrome Extension: How to Disable Page Visibility API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660653/chrome-extension-how-to-disable-page-visibility-api)

```
for (event_name of ["visibilitychange", "webkitvisibilitychange", "blur"]) {
window.addEventListener(event_name, function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, true);
```

Is there any way to disable the page visibility api on facebook?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The site may be using different check e.g. document.hasFocus() or even requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: Be aware that Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them so don't be surprised if you get banned.

Comment: @wOxxOm I checked but I don't know which event is called when we leave focus from the active tab

Comment: @WizKid I have put some delay to make the ext work like human, so my ext can work perfect if the tab is active

Comment: @vtnguyen, put your current code in a [script element using a content script](/a/9517879) with `"run_at":"document_start"`.